# Pig Script Merging Rows after join and group by

Tags: merge, dataset, apache-pig, rows, movie

**Movie table**:

```
id  movie  genre
1   ABC    A|B|C
2   DEF    D|A|F
```

There are multiple genres which are separated by a `|` delimiter.

**Ratings table:**

```
user_id  movie_id  rating
1        1         3.5
1        2         4.5
```

**Result:**

I want the result as `user_id` + all genres

```
user_id  genres
1        (A|B|C|D|A|F)
```

**Code:**

```
genre_data = join movie by id, ratings by movie_id;
genre_data = group genre_data by (user_id);
user1_data = foreach genre_data generate ratings::user_id, movie::genre;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by:

```
genre_data = join movie by id, ratings by movie_id;
genre_data = group genre_data by user_id;

user_data = foreach genre_data {
    genres = foreach genre_data generate movie::genre as genres;
    generate group as user_id, BagToString(genres, '|');
};
```